# Why does this regular expression crash the browser? (using regexp.exec)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been playing around with an expression in JavaScript to match some basic import statements, and I've found that the following crashes both the browser tab (Chrome) and NodeJS (you've been warned):

```js
const rexp = /^(import|const|let|var)\s\{\s*(([a-zA-Z0-9_]+,?\s*)+)\}\s(from\s"|=\srequire\(")([a-zA-Z0-9\.\/_-]+)("\)|")/gm;
const match = rexp.exec('import { EVENT_NAME_PROPERTY, getSomething } from "@company/test";');
```

What happens here?

I've tracked the actual glitch to the second last capture group `([a-zA-Z0-9\.\/_-]+)` - If I add the `@` character to it, no crash occurs. It seems to crash in some environments and just hangs in others. Regexpal.com crashes completely, whereas jsbin simply hangs for a while.

As you can probably see by the expression, I'm trying to extract certain parts of import/require statements. As mentioned above adding the `@` fixes the glitch and I am able to extract the matched components.

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+,?\s*)+` is highly suspect and should probably be `([a-zA-Z0-9_],?\s*)+` or even `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_],?\s*)+`.

Comment: Indeed this was a duplicate.. And following the linked post led me to revising the expression: `^(import|const|let|var)\s\{\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*)\s*\}\s(from\s"|=\srequire\(")([a-zA-Z0-9@\.\/_-]+)("\)|")`. This now works correctly and doesn't have the dangerous optionals in the segment matching the imported variable names.